# Square Connect V2 API: Will ListTransactions for a time period guarantee all refunds for that time period are returned?

Tags: square-connect

I am trying to make sure I get all transactions and refunds for a location for a given time period. Is it enough to query the ListTransactions endpoint? Or could there be refunds that are returned by ListRefunds that would not be contained in the transactions response?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListTransactions` will have all the transactions.